# regEx text replace using | and () capture issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javaScript RegEx literals to replace parts of a string, 
i want to use | to check for different types of patterns that may occur and () to capture a part of the match i want to replace. it doesn't seem to work though, why is this?

here's my current regEx:

```
testText.replace(/(\w)\s+\w$|(\w)\s+$|\w+(\w)$/g, "$1...")
```

I'm guessing somethings wrong with it: here's want i want to acheieve:

given "x x" i expect:

```
  "x..."
```

given "x   " I expect:

```
   "x...
```

given "werfdsdfasd" (word with no space) I expect:

```
   "werfdsdfasd..."
```

Comment: You should capture what you need to keep. See https://regex101.com/r/NdLkcQ/1. Try `.replace(/(\w)\s+\w$|(\w)\s+$|(\w+)\w$/g, '$1$2$3...')`. Or https://regex101.com/r/NdLkcQ/2, `replace(/(\w)\s+\w?$|(\w+)\w$/g, '$1$2...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have 3 capture groups and you always reference the first one.

Try this: `(\w+)(?:\s+\w$|\s+$|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UjRiqR/2)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to capture anything that comes before a space or end of line.

```
(\w+)(\s+.*$|$)
```